# Laravel eloquent/collection select only matching records for all requested users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a polymorphic "Relationships" many to many relation that looks like that:

```
users
id | first_name | last_name

groups
id | group_name

regions
id | region_name

relationships
id | user_id | relationship_id | relationship_type | relationship_level
 4 |      13 |              25 |         App\Group |      Group Manager
 5 |      20 |              18 |        App\Region |        Participant
```

And the relationship looks like that:

```
public function regions()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Region', 'relationship')->withPivot('relationship_level')->withTimestamps();
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Group', 'relationship')->withPivot('relationship_level')->withTimestamps();
}
```

And vice versa.

When I have an array of IDs, I want to select the relationships that **exactly match** between the users, this means that all columns (except user_id) match.

And they should only be rows that match among **all** users. If only 10 out of 12 selected users have the same relationship it should not be included.

If I select 10 users I need to select a pivot record that all those 10 users have (if any).

It doesn't matter if done in eloquent or via the collection after fetching from Database.

Comment: To clarify, you want to return only the users that have the same relationship_id, relationship_type, and relationship_level?

Comment: No, I have an array of users ids, I want to return only relationships that ALL those users have. If all those users are "Group Managers" to App\Group with ID 50 - i want to return that relationship.

Comment: So return users separated by group type (relationship_level)?

Comment: I don't want to return users, I want to return Relationships (pivot) records that are equal for all requested users. Or am I not understanding what you're saying?

Comment: Have you tried to write raw SQL query and run it? Sometimes it will be easier to write (and maintain) raw query instead using Eloquent methods.

Comment: Something like `select relationship_type from relationships inner join users on users.id = relationships.user_id where users.id in (...) group by relationships.relationship_type`

Comment: @Tarasovych Shouldn't I group by all three parameters? And wont this return a relationship even if 
only one of the users has it?

Comment: @MaximilianBerbechelov it depends on what do you want to get in result...

Comment: I want to get only relationships that all users have. If I have 15 users - they would all have diferent "Relationship" table records and we don't care about hose. But if all 15 of them have a record with the same type,level and id - we want that Relationship table record.